# change theme when clicking on span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a function to get id of the .themechoice span when a quote is clicked, and store it in the variable 'theme' so that the function below changes the theme of the sections to the matching .themeChoice span id

jq

```
$('.themeChoice').click(function() {
var theme = //need function here
$(this).parent().find('section').addClass(theme);
});   //end click a theme
```

html
in head tag

```
        <style>
        .light {
            background-color: lightyellow;
            border: double lightgreen small;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 1em;
        }
        .dark {
            background-color: black;
            border: groove darkgray medium;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 1em;
        }
        .neutral {
            background-color: tan;
            border: inset brown thick;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 1em;
            margin: 1em;
        }
        img {
            width: 200px;
        }   
    </style>
```

html in body

```
<section>
  <p><h3>Pick a theme by clicking the quote you like most</h3></p>
  <span="" id="light" class="themeChoice"><p>Future's so bright, you'll need sunshades.</p></span>
  <span id="dark" class="themeChoice"><p>“Everyone is a moon, and has a dark side which he never shows to anybody.” -Mark Twain</p></span>
  <span id="neutral" class="themeChoice"><p>“The hottest place in Hell is reserved for those who remain neutral in times of great moral conflict.” -Martin Luther King, Jr.</p></span>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I ended up using this and it worked great:

```
$('.themeChoice').click(function() {
var theme = this.id;
$('section').addClass(theme);
});
```

Thank you both for this.id, that helped immensely.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.id` to get the clicked element's id, and that is the class name here.

```
$('.themeChoice').click(function() {
  var theme = this.id;
  $(this).parent("section").addClass(theme);
});
```

Also, in your case parent element of `.themeChoice` is the section. The selector that you have used is wrong.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/frwru7zj/1/)

And a stable code that removes the previous theme class and add the newer one is given below,

```
$('.themeChoice').click(function() {
  var theme = this.id;
  var $parent = $(this).parent("section");
  $parent.removeClass($parent.data("theme")).addClass(theme);
  $parent.data("theme", theme);
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/frwru7zj/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery().click()` function accepts a callback, like you added one. That callback gets called within the context of the clicked element so `this` inside of your click handler is referring to the clicked element so you can do:

```
$('.themeChoice').click(function() {
   var theme = $(this).attr('id'); //Should return the id of clicked element a shortcut would be this.id like mentioned by another user
  //Your class adding stuff
});
```